# how to add package dependencies to stack project

Tags: haskell

how to add package dependencies to stack project. for example lets say I want to add `Parsec` dependencies to my project so I can import it in a given module and use it

I have added the package name the cable file and I have got the following error :
`Unable to parse cabal file /Users/lambda/development/blog-post/blog-post.cabal: NoParse "build-depends" 19`

my cabal file is as per the below

```
 build-depends:       base >= 4.7 && < 5
                      ,parsec-3.1.11
```

Comment: you have to add the dependency to the `build-depends` section in your `cabal`-file.

Comment: If you come across any issues please post the errors - otherwise helping you will be difficult.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the syntax you use in your cabal file is not valid

```
build-depends:       base >= 4.7 && < 5
             ,       parsec >= 3.1.11 && < 4
```

should be correct

### update

the syntax `parsec >= 3.1.11 && < 4` is not mere convention but a way to constrain the used library to the bounds, where your package works.

`parsec >= 3.1.11 && < 4` means that the version of `parsec` needs to be larger or equal to version `3.1.11` and strictly less than `4`.

Comment: I am not sure, but I think `parsec` is not developed anymore and `mega-parsec` is the de-facto successor.

Comment: It works actually, is it a convention to write the package name and `>> current version && <... `